# Cannot Create New Team Project TFS2010 TF249063 TF218017

Tags: sharepoint, tfs

Server: Windows 2008 R2 Standard

Team Foundation Server 2010

WSS 3.0

TFS Configuration: Single Server instalation (including SharePoint)

**The following error occurs when trying to create a new team project from my local machine. The  ://sourcecontrol site and  ://sourcecontrol/sites/DefaultCollection/ site appears to be functioning fine and my user is a Site collection administrator on both.  I can navigate both sites through a browser on my local machine.  Thanks for your help!**

2010-04-23T10:01:42 | Module: Internal | Team Foundation Server proxy retrieved | Completion time: 0 seconds
2010-04-23T10:01:42 | Module: Wizard | Retrieved IAuthorizationService proxy | Completion time: 0 seconds
2010-04-23T10:01:42 | Module: Wizard | TF30227: Project creation permissions retrieved | Completion time: 0.109382 seconds
2010-04-23T10:01:42 | Module: Internal | The template information for Team Foundation Server "sourcecontrol\DefaultCollection" was retrieved from the Team Foundation Server. |

Completion time: 0.15626 seconds
---begin Exception entry---
Time: 2010-04-23T10:03:24
Module: Wizard
Exception Message: TF218017: A SharePoint site could not be created for use as the team project portal. The following error occurred: TF249063: The following Web service is

not available: ://sourcecontrol/_vti_bin/TeamFoundationIntegrationService.asmx. This Web service is used for the Team Foundation Server Extensions for SharePoint Products.

The underlying error is: The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server.. Verify that the following URL points

to a valid SharePoint Web application and that the application is available: ://sourcecontrol. If the URL is correct and the Web application is operating normally, verify

that a firewall is not blocking access to the Web application. (type TeamFoundationServerException)

Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.WssSiteCreator.CheckCreateSite(TfsTeamProjectCollection tfsServer, Uri adminUri, Uri siteUri)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.WssSiteCreator.ValidateSettings(ProjectCreationContext context)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.PortfolioProjectForm.OnFinish()

Inner Exception Details:

Exception Message: TF249063: The following Web service is not available: ://sourcecontrol/_vti_bin/TeamFoundationIntegrationService.asmx. This Web service is used for the

Team Foundation Server Extensions for SharePoint Products. The underlying error is: The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was

closed by the server.. Verify that the following URL points to a valid SharePoint Web application and that the application is available: ://sourcecontrol. If the URL is

correct and the Web application is operating normally, verify that a firewall is not blocking access to the Web application. (type TeamFoundationServiceUnavailableException)

Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.SharePoint.SharePointTeamFoundationIntegrationService.HandleException(Exception e)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.SharePoint.SharePointTeamFoundationIntegrationService.CheckUrl(String absolutePath, CheckUrlOptions options, Guid configurationServerId,

Guid projectCollectionId)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.SharePoint.WssUtilities.CheckUrl(ICredentials credentials, Uri adminUrl, Uri siteUrl, CheckUrlOptions options, Guid

configurationServerId, Guid projectCollectionId)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.SharePoint.WssUtilities.CheckCreateSite(TfsConnection tfs, Uri adminUrl, Uri siteUrl)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.WssSiteCreator.CheckCreateSite(TfsTeamProjectCollection tfsServer, Uri adminUri, Uri siteUri)

Inner Exception Details:

Exception Message: The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server. (type WebException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Net.WebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationClientProxyBase.AsyncWebRequest.ExecRequest(Object obj)

Inner Exception Details:

Exception Message: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. (type IOException)

Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(WebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)

Inner Exception Details:

Exception Message: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host (type SocketException)

Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)

--- end Exception entry ---

Comment: Reduce all the error stuff ... e.g. to "It says: This Web service is used for the Team Foundation Server Extensions for SharePoint Products."

Answer (score 0):

Was SharePoint installed on the box by the Team Foundation Server setup, or you have manually installed and configured SharePoint? Based on the error message it looks like there is a problem with the TeamFoundationIntegrationService.asmx web service.

Could you please open Internet Explorer and navigate to http://sourcecontrol/_vti_bin/TeamFoundationIntegrationService.asmx and let me know what you see (blank page, error, page loads successfully). If you open Team Foundation Server Administration Console and click on the "Extensions for SharePoint Products" can you see your SharePoint web application listed?

Also I would try the following in the Administration Console:

- Click on the SharePoint Web Application
- Select the SharePoint Web Application
- Click on the "Repair Connection" link on the right side
- Try to create a new team project

Let me know how it goes.
Ladislau

Comment: Thanks for your help.
While on the server(sourcecontrol) I see a list of about 16 web methods. While from another machine, I get Page Cannot Be displayed.

Comment: i hve the same problem and did, like you said. "Webpage cannot be found" is the Browser answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced something similar, that creating a team project would just (upon clicking Finish) just give back an error of "Object reference not set".

After 6 hours of researching and confirming multiple security and environment settings - all which were correct, I found the problem being a corrupted cache for VS2010 Team Explorer.

**The Fix** [Windows 7]

1) Close all instances of VS2010
2) Navigate to 
    *C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\2.0\Cache* and 
    *C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\3.0\Cache*
    and delete all content in these folder.
   !!Do NOT delete the "Cache" folders themselves, only the content.
3) Restart VS2010 and now create your new team project.

worked for me, hope it helps!